# SQL Like advanced cmd

Tags: ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access 2013

I need to make a query so that the program can grab the last name of the ACTOR'S NAME when the ACTOR'S name has their full name for example Kelly Garman, and Weird Al Yankovic. Yankovic has 3 values and Garman has 2 values. Any help?

There are over 10,000 records with tons of different names, so I need to have it so the user will be asked to input the last name and once they do, the database will query by the last name.

Its also a query where the user inputs something in when asked.

Columns in the database are in the SELECT statement

```
SELECT [RECORD #], [ACTOR'S NAME], [PRODUCTION NAME]
FROM Actors AS A
WHERE [A.ACTOR'S NAME] = [What's the last name?]
```

The Database file is here. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B19CRcQGkXoVTTZpaldDWnFuS28

Comment: Wait, do you want to *return* the actors last name, or *search by* the actor's last name?

Comment: Yeah, the user has to put in the last name, and then all the last names will show up in the query. For example, I put in Yankovic and all the productions that he was in by his last name are queried.

Comment: Your question isnt clear. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
We need sample data and desire output to find an answer faster, otherwise we will be wasting time guessing what you need. You also could create your schema with data using **http://www.sqlfiddle.com**

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE actors_full_name LIKE '%Last Name Input'`

Comment: Please create an example for your question in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: You tagged it mysql...

Comment: I removed the tag. I didn't know that mysql was different. lol

Comment: @computerfreako2 I've done my best to convert my answer to MS Access, but I don't have a copy to try it.

Comment: @Schwern This is my very first question so I learned a lot about how to post questions correctly. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pattern match in the `WHERE` clause.

```
PARAMETERS [What's the last name?] Text ( 255 );
SELECT A.[Record #], A.[ACTOR'S NAME]
FROM Actors AS A
WHERE A.[ACTOR'S NAME] ALike '% ' & [What's the last name?];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I didn't include the PARAMETERS line, but I included everything else and it works. I am excited! Also, the A.[ACTOR'S NAME] should be [A.ACTOR'S NAME]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [REVERSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) along with [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) as below to get the last name.

```
REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE([ACTOR'S NAME]), 1, INSTR(' ', REVERSE([ACTOR'S NAME])) - 1))
```

Comment: I don't understand SUBSTRING or the REVERSE cmd

Comment: @computerfreako2 This is getting the last name by looking for everything after the last space in the name. However, many SQL databases only have functions to find the *first* space. So Raghavan has cleverly reversed the name, found everything up to the first space (which is really the last), and then reversed that again. However this is all unnecessary because MySQL can find the last space with SUBSTRING_INDEX(). [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33359861/14660).

Comment: I was looking for MS Access SQL code. Removed mysql code. Sorry!

Comment: @Schwern This is my very first question so I learned a lot about how to post questions correctly. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

To find the last name you need to get the word after the last space. You can't do this directly in MS Access.  Instead, you can find the position of the last space with [`InstrRev(Name, ' ')`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/instrrev.php). Then use [`Right`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/right.php) to get everything to the right of that, but that takes a position from the *end* of the string.  To get that, subtract what you got from `InstrRev` from the length of the name.

```
SELECT Right(Name, Len(Name) - InstrRev(Name, ' ')) as 'Last Name'
FROM Actors
WHERE Right(Name, Len(Name) - InstrRev(Name, ' ')) = 'Yankovic';
```

Unfortunately I do not have a copy of MS Access to test this.

Comment: I didn't even learn Len or InstrRev so maybe my teacher is not even looking for that. lol

Comment: Is there a way to include user input too, so that it will ask a user to input a last name. There are a bunch of names the database with over 10,000 records

Comment: @computerfreako2 Sorry, I don't know Access. I'm working from the documentation.